# Vue app compiles successfully but does not load in browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, localhost, vue-cli

I have a Vue app that outputs the following in the console after `npm run serve`.

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 17450ms                                                                                         2:15:55 PM


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://10.0.0.72:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.

No issues found.
```

However, the app will not load on `http://localhost:8080/` . The page displays the **"This site cannot be reached.The connection was reset."** message.

Other pages load fine, including the Node server I am using for the backend, running on `localhost:3002`.

I have tried removing the `node_modules` and running `npm install` again, but that hasn't fixed it. With the app compiling ok there is little help troubleshoot. There are also no errors in the browser dev tools console.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong or how to debug this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change your port with `npm run serve --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 4000` and then run again.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Actually I used this in `nuxt` app and it's worked fine for me. Btw thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with the following command:

```
npm run serve -- --port <alternative port number>
```

The `--hostname 0.0.0.0` part of the answer below did not work for me.

I guess the `--` alone will specify the default localhost address before the port.